# How can I generate a report in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, test-reporting

I am using java and Selenium WebDriver.

How can I generate report in Selenium WebDriver using java? I don't want JUnit or TestNG report.

Does anyone can help?

Comment: Just curious, why is that you do not want to use JUnit or TestNG?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up ANT and ANT reports gives you output report more detailed than the regular TestNG or Junit report. You can customize your reports as well.

Comment: The poster doesn't want to use JUnit or TestNG. This is the question. So, the answer should be considered without JUnit or TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

Maven "surefire plugin" , Gradle, Ant, TestNG, SauceLabs , etc.   They all have reporting capabilities.  You just need to write the code that generates a JUnit compatable report and which ever build tool you use (listed above) should be able to parse the result into an HTML file.

More advanced: If you want to generate your own report from the JUnit XML result or your own custom XML result, you can use a XSLT transformation to render HTML files from your XML results.   Also, if you use Jenkins for CI then it can also render a report for you.